# Haskell parsing input

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to parse Int values from IO to a list of list. 
t -> no of input test cases
n -> no of elements in the array
k -> sum value of array/any int value

input:

```
3               -> t (no of input test cases)
4 3              -> n, k (no of arr, some int value)
-1 -3 4 2        -> arr
4 2              -> n, k (no of arr, some int value)
0 -1 2 1         -> arr
5 2              -> n, k (no of arr, some int value)
2 1 0 -2 -1      -> arr
```

Expected output:
`[[3,-1,-3,4,2],[2,0,-1,2,1],[2,2,1,0,-2,-1]]` -> list of list

```
import System.IO

solve :: [Int] -> String
solve (k:arr) 
    | len < k   = "YES"
    | otherwise = "NO"
    where
        len = length $ filter (<=0) arr

parseIn :: IO() -> [[Int]]
parseIn = do
    t <- readLn :: IO Int
    inputs <- forM_ [1..t] $ (\_ -> do
        [n,k] <- map (read :: String -> Int) . words . getLine
        arr   <- map (read :: String -> Int) . words . getLine
        return [k:arr])
    return inputs

main = interact $ unlines . map solve . parseIn
```

Can someone please help me solve this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. please find my solution below

```
import Control.Monad

solve :: [Int] -> String
solve (k:arr)
    | len < k   = "YES"
    | otherwise = "NO"
    where
        len = length $ filter (<=0) arr

parseIn :: IO [[Int]]
parseIn = do
    t <- readLn :: IO Int
    forM [1..t] $ \_ -> do
        [n,k] <- map read <$> words <$> getLine
        arr   <- map read <$> words <$> getLine
        return (k:arr)

main =  do
  res <- map solve <$> parseIn
  print res
```

Comment: This does not meet your input / output expectations that you put into your question.

Comment: The problem you had was because of the code `[k:arr]`, this would have made the signature `parseIn :: IO [[[Int]]]` and how you wanted to use the `interact` function. Its signature is `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()` so your `parseIn` should simply have been `parseIn :: String -> [[Int]]`. So it should not do any IO on it's own

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly, what you are trying to achieve with the `solve` function, but for your given example and the expected output, this should do.

The important bit is the `inputNumbers` function that retries reading numbers from the command line until a valid input is entered.

The `readNumbers` function uses the [monadic](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/Maybe) properties of `Maybe`. As soon as one of the words can not be read as an `Int`, the rest is skipped and `Nothing` is returned. `readLn` is not very useful here, as you want to enter the list of numbers as a space seperated string and not in Haskell's list format, e.g. `1 2 3` instead of `[1, 2, 3]`.

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Control.Monad (forM)

-- tries to parse a space seperated list of given
-- number of numbers from the given string
readNumbers :: Int -> String -> Maybe [Int]
readNumbers n input
    | length split == n = mapM readMaybe split -- try to read numbers
    | otherwise = Nothing
  where split = words input -- split at spaces

inputNumbers :: Int -> IO [Int]
inputNumbers n = do
    -- read one line from the commandline
    input <- getLine
    -- try to parse list of numbers of given length
    case readNumbers n input of
        Just nums -> return nums -- return the parsed numbers
        Nothing -> do
            -- invalid input: retry
            putStrLn $ "Invalid input: " ++ input
            inputNumbers n

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- read the number of tries
    [t] <- inputNumbers 1
    arrs <- forM [1..t] $ \_ -> do
        -- read the list length and an int value
        [n, k] <- inputNumbers 2
        -- read the list of the given length
        arr <- inputNumbers n
        -- return the read list with prepended k
        return $ k:arr
    -- print result
    print arrs
```

Comment: the output he provided was an example for the output of the `parseIn` function not the whole program